# automorphisms and field extension $E$ of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

I want a hint. That is all I ask for. The question I am asked to prove is as follows:

Let $E$ be an extension field of $\mathbb{Q}$. Show that any automorphisn of $E$ acts as the identity on $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* What is $\phi(0), \phi(1), \phi(n+1)),\phi(-n), \phi(n/m)$?

Comment: $\phi(0)$=0,$\phi(1)$=1,$\phi(n+1)$=$\phi(n)$+$\phi(1)$=$\phi(n)$+1,$\phi(-n)$=-$\phi(n)$, and $\phi(\frac{n}{m})$=$\frac{\phi(n)}{\phi(m)}$

Comment: @HowardRoark, note that $\phi(2) = \phi(1) + \phi(1) = 1 + 1 = 2$. Now try and use induction.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\phi(1) = 1 \implies \phi(n) =n$ for every $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.  Also, $\phi(n^{-1}) = \phi(n)^{-1}$

Comment: I guess my main issue is understanding what an automorphism is exactly. I know it is defined to be an isomorphism from a set to itself. But what is confusing me is whether $\phi(n)$ has to map to $n$ for all $n\in \mathbb{z}$

Comment: @HowardRoark A field automorphism is a ring isomorphism from the field onto itself.  In this case, your ring would be the field extension $E$ of $\mathbb{Q}$.  Since fields have unity, we have $\phi(1) = 1$, so for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, we have $\phi(n) = \phi(1 + \dots + 1) = 1 + \dots + 1 = n$.

Answer (score 0):

Look at what this automorphism preserves in terms of the field structure on $E$. Can you "cover" $\mathbb{Q}$ by invariant elements?